Preventing access to htdocs folder of XAMPP from specific ip and domain
Subdomain is redirected to vps via A record in DNS and XAMPP is running in vps. I want to prevent access to htdocs of XAMPP from ip of the vps and the subdomain. How to edit the .htaccess file for this purpose?

Take a look at the documentation of the access module, it will answer your question: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html
